# Update one duplicate record and delete the rest of them - Classic ASP & SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to update one duplicate record and delete the rest of them

I have a table...

```
id    start unit
1      1      a
2      1      a
3      2      a
4      2      a
5      3      b
```

which I want to turn into...

```
id    start  unit
1      1       b
3      2       b
5      3       b
```

I have sorted out finding the duplicates but I'm failing to be able to do anything with them - or in the example below I end up deleting all the duplicates and not keeping the first record.
I'm also not convinced that this method will be the best way to approach the problem

```
strSQL_dup = "SELECT start_date, id 
              FROM test 
              WHERE start_date IN 
                 (SELECT start_date 
                 FROM test WHERE adId = " & adId & " AND Unit = " & scId & " 
                 GROUP BY start_date HAVING (COUNT(start_date ) > 1) ) 
                 GROUP BY test.id, start_date"
Set rsSQL_dup = conn.Execute(strSQL_dup)

Do While Not rsSQL_dup.EOF

        start_date = rsSQL_dup.Fields("start_date").value
        id = rsSQL_dup.Fields("id").value   

        'Response.Write("<p> "&start_date&" | "& id & " update me </p>"

        if bookingstate = "Provisional" Then
                    dateStatusNo = 8
                else
                    dateStatusNo = 1
                End if

                'Response.Write("<p> " & id & " update me</p>")

                strSQL_dup_update = "UPDATE test SET  Unit = '" & dateStatusNo & "' WHERE id = '" & id & "' "
                Set rsSQL_dup_update = conn.Execute(strSQL_dup_update)


        strSQL_delete = "SELECT top 1 start_date, id FROM test WHERE start_date =  " & start_date
        Set rsSQL_delete = conn.Execute(strSQL_delete)
                Do While Not rsSQL_delete.EOF
                        start_date = rsSQL_delete.Fields("start_date").value
                        id = rsSQL_delete.Fields("id").value

                        'Response.Write("<p> "&start_date&" | "& id & " delete me</p>")

                        strSQL_dup_delet = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id = '" & id & "' "
                        Set rsSQL_dup_delet = conn.Execute(strSQL_dup_delet)

        rsSQL_delete.MoveNext()  
Loop
rsSQL_dup.MoveNext()  
Loop 'End Do While Not rsSQL_dup.EOF
Loop
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. How, for instance, do rows with IDs 2 and 3 (which both have units `a`) turn into one row with units `b')? (Same question applies to IDs 4 and 5, BTW, which are units `a` and `b` but turn into just `b`.)

Comment: My (badly constructed) plan was to select the duplicates, update column "unit", then delete one of the duplicate rows.  Or it could work by removing the duplicate and then updating the remaining row?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. :-) How do two rows with units `a` magically convert into one row with units `b`? What's the logic for the transformation? And, along the same vein, how do you decide which one to keep and which one to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i agree with @Ken white how a change into b but if you want to  remove duplicate record

why dont you use distinct command like

```
select distinct start_date 
          FROM test
```

and if you want your query to run then you can combine it with your query like

```
 select distinct start_date 
          FROM test WHERE start_date IN 
             (SELECT start_date 
             FROM test WHERE adId = " & adId & " AND Unit = " & scId & " 
             GROUP BY start_date HAVING (COUNT(start_date ) > 1) ) 
             GROUP BY test.id, start_date"
```

and if you want to delete records then use this query

```
WITH test AS(
SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
   RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM test WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest.  You can probably put this together with a `merge` or multiple statements in a transaction.  But, why not just create a temporary table, truncate the original table, and then re-insert the data?

```
select min(id), start, 'b' as unit
into #test
from test
group by start;

truncate table test;

insert into test(id, start, unit)
    select id, start, unit
    from #test;
```

drop table #test;